# How to use MagicalRecord with AFIncrementalStore

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, magicalrecord

If there is someone who was able to use `MagicalRecord` with `AFIncrementalStore` could you please explain how to use them together?

I'm trying to configure `MagicalRecord` to use `AFIncrementalStore` but when I make fetch request the app hangs. I can see that `AFIncrementalStore` makes request to API server and receive response but after that the UI become unresponsive.

Here is my configuration of `MagicalRecord + AFIncrementalStore`:

```
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [NSManagedObjectModel MR_defaultManagedObjectModel];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];

AFIncrementalStore *incrementalStore = (AFIncrementalStore *)[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:[APIIncrementalStore type] configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:nil];

NSDictionary *options = @{
    NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @(YES),
    NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @(YES)
};

[incrementalStore.backingPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_addSqliteStoreNamed:@"DB.sqlite" withOptions:options];
[NSPersistentStore MR_setDefaultPersistentStore:incrementalStore];
[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator MR_setDefaultStoreCoordinator:incrementalStore.persistentStoreCoordinator];
[NSManagedObjectContext MR_initializeDefaultContextWithCoordinator:incrementalStore.persistentStoreCoordinator];
```

The fetch request looks like that:

```
[Card MR_fetchAllSortedBy:@"number" ascending:YES withPredicate:nil groupBy:nil delegate:self];
```

Comment: It looks like you're ignoring errors when adding your store. Have you tried seeing if there are any errors?

Comment: casademora, thank you for tip, I've tried added error handling like that:
`NSError *error;
AFIncrementalStore *incrementalStore = (AFIncrementalStore *)[persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:[APIIncrementalStore type] configuration:nil URL:nil options:nil error:&error];
    
if(error) {
   NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}`

But unfortunately it doesn't show any errors.